# Changing folder name in Python

Tags: python

I need a super simple script that changes the names of the subfolders of the actual folder

Here's a little example for better understanding. 
Im in the folder **My Music** and I want to change tha name of all the subfolders (**This_Is_A_Example_Subpath**):

C:/My Music/This_Is_A_Example_- Subpath
C:/My Music/This_Is_A_Example_- Subpath1
C:/My Music/This_Is_A_Example_- Subpath2

I want to change to:

C:/My Music/This Is - A Example - Subpath
C:/My Music/This Is - A Example - Subpath1
C:/My Music/This Is - A Example - Subpath2

Comment: make sure if you like the answer that you accept it, I see you've asked a few questions but haven't accepted any answers.

Comment: Sorry for that Chris, I'm new with this.

Comment: Not a problem, you're doing fine :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import os
import os.path

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('C:/My Music/'):
    for idx in range(len(dirnames)):
        newname = dirnames[idx].replace('_', ' ')
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, dirnames[idx]), os.path.join(dirpath, newname))
        dirnames[idx] = newname
```

A bit of an explanation here. This walks through all of the subdirectories using `os.walk`. However since you're changing the name of the directory *as you're traversing the tree*, you need to update the directory names that it's going to walk. So this (1) renames the directory, and (2) updates the list so that it walks the newly-named directories.